# How to Rename Multiple Files With Their First 10 Characters?

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I am having a problem to rename multiple files by replacing the name by their first 10 characters of their old name. I tried to find the solution in internet but I didn't find the answers.

Example:

Original File Names:

```
1208605001abAcd.jpg 
1201230111FbcAdee.jpg 
11512345714x611aaa.jpg
```

What I want to achieve:

```
1208605001.jpg 
1201230111.jpg 
1151234571.jpg
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try:

```
rename -n 's/(.{10}).*(\.jpg)$/$1$2/' *.jpg
```

Example:

```
$ rename -n 's/(.{10}).*(\.jpg)$/$1$2/' *.jpg
11512345714x611aaa.jpg -> 1151234571.jpg
1201230111FbcAdee.jpg -> 1201230111.jpg
1208605001abAcd.jpg -> 1208605001.jpg
```

The `-n` option only simulates the command, so that you can verify the changes. Run without it to actually make the changes.

The regex `(.{10}).*(\.jpg)` consists:

- `.{10}` - any 10 characters, in a group `(…)`, followed by
- `.*` - any number of any characters followed by
- `\.jpg$` - the extension at the end (`$`) of the filename, in the second group

The replacement `$1$2` is just the first group followed by the second.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, when I tried to run your suggested command I've got this message : "Substitution replacement not terminated at (eval 1) line 1.". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @surya_darmana there was supposed to be a `/` after `$2`. The example output has it correct. I have fixed it.

Comment: Thank you very much, the command is run perfectly, you made my day :D

Comment: This holds for the `rename`  that comes with `perl` (e.g. on Ubuntu), not the one that comes with `util-linux` (e.g. on Fedora, CentOS, Cygwin).

Answer (score 5):

You can do with only bash:

```
for FILE in *.jpg ; do mv "${FILE}" "${FILE:0:10}.jpg" ; done
```

With a little work you can get file extension and add automagically to the new name.

Comment: Use globbing (`*`) instead of `ls` (for which you wouldn't need the `-1` anyway), and quote the variables. (`"${FILE:0:10}.jpg"`).

Comment: I prefer using ls, but +1 for the quoting! (error of distraction).

Comment: It isn't a matter of preference, using `ls` will break on files with spaces in the name. Globbing won't.

Comment: Great, @Kevin! I never thought about IFS. I'm "old", I'm yet naming my files with underscore instead of spaces. :-)
I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `zsh`:

```
zmv '(*).(*)' '${1:0:10}.$2'
```

If it's not already done, you may need to first run:

```
autoload zmv
```

Comment: Will this keep the extensions?

Comment: @muru no, I didn't notice that particular requirement. Updated with a version that does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GUI version, take a look at pyRenamer, a powerful bulk-renaming tool.

[image: Logo for pyRenamer]

pyRenamer has two great advantages. One is that it allows you do a "what if", in other words to see what would happen before you commit to the change.

The other advantage is explained nicely in its description:

> You can rename files using patterns, search and replace,
>   substitutions, insert or delete text, or even rename files manually.
>
> You can also rename images using their EXIF tags and music using their
>   internal tags.

To install, use Ubuntu Software Centre or your favourite software installer, or use the command line issue the following command:

```
sudo apt install pyrenamer
```